# SwiftUI: Change “About View” in macOS app

Tags: swift, swiftui, menuitem, nsmenu, about-box

I am building a macOS-app using `SwiftUI` and the new `App` lifecycle.

I would love to change the contents of the “About Window” (that appears when you tap “About DemoApp” in the apps’ menu) but have no idea how:

[image]

**How can I replace the About view with a custom one?**

Comment: Other people have answered the question but I'd like to leave a link to [this](https://lostmoa.com/blog/CustomiseAboutPanelOnMacOSInSwiftUI/) blogpost that I found useful about getting in an attributed string into the existing 'about' window. This is great when you just need to add small pieces of information.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it but it does require creating an AppDelegate. Here's what your AppFile should look like:

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.appInfo) {
                Button(action: {
                    appDelegate.showAboutPanel()
                }) {
                    Text("About My App")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your AppDelegate Should Look like this:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var aboutBoxWindowController: NSWindowController?

    func showAboutPanel() {
        if aboutBoxWindowController == nil {
            let styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [.closable, .miniaturizable,/* .resizable,*/ .titled]
            let window = NSWindow()
            window.styleMask = styleMask
            window.title = "About My App"
            window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: AboutView())
            aboutBoxWindowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
        }

        aboutBoxWindowController?.showWindow(aboutBoxWindowController?.window)
    }
}
```

Then, just make a SwiftUI View named AboutView and it'll display that in your About Box. For Example:

```
struct AboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Hello, World!")
                Spacer()
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 300, minHeight: 300)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a Credits.rtf file to your Bundle. This will be automatically detect and be inserted in the About Dialog.

You can find more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/aboutpaneloptionkey/2869609-credits)

Comment: Really appreciate your help, @davidev! This is super helpful in case you want to add credits to the existing About Panel. However I am asking about how to completely replace that panel with my very own view, I don’t want just to customise the default one.

Answer (score 5):

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct AboutView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(nsImage: NSImage(named: "AppIcon")!)
            
            Text("\(Bundle.main.appName)")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                // Xcode 13.0 beta 2
                //.textSelection(.enabled)
            
            Link("\(AboutView.offSiteAdr.replace(of: "http://", to: ""))", destination: AboutView.offCiteUrl )
            
            Text("Ver: \(Bundle.main.appVersionLong) (\(Bundle.main.appBuild)) ")
                // Xcode 13.0 beta 2
                //.textSelection(.enabled)
            
            Text(Bundle.main.copyright)
                .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .thin))
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
        }
        .padding(20)
        .frame(minWidth: 350, minHeight: 300)
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////
/// HELPERS
//////////////////////////////////
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    private var aboutBoxWindowController: NSWindowController?
    
    func showAboutWnd() {
        if aboutBoxWindowController == nil {
            let styleMask: NSWindow.StyleMask = [.closable, .miniaturizable,/* .resizable,*/ .titled]
            let window = NSWindow()
            window.styleMask = styleMask
            window.title = "About \(Bundle.main.appName)"
            window.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: AboutView())
            window.center()
            aboutBoxWindowController = NSWindowController(window: window)
        }
        
        aboutBoxWindowController?.showWindow(aboutBoxWindowController?.window)
    }
}

extension AboutView {
    private static var offSiteAdr: String { "http://www.taogit.com" }
    private static var offEmail: String { "someUser@gmail.com" }
    
    public static var offCiteUrl: URL { URL(string: AboutView.offSiteAdr )! }
    public static var offEmailUrl: URL { URL(string: "mailto:\(AboutView.offEmail)")! }
}
extension Bundle {
    public var appName: String { getInfo("CFBundleName")  }
    //public var displayName: String {getInfo("CFBundleDisplayName")}
    //public var language: String {getInfo("CFBundleDevelopmentRegion")}
    //public var identifier: String {getInfo("CFBundleIdentifier")}
    public var copyright: String {getInfo("NSHumanReadableCopyright").replace(of: "\\\\n", to: "\n") }
    
    public var appBuild: String { getInfo("CFBundleVersion") }
    public var appVersionLong: String { getInfo("CFBundleShortVersionString") }
    //public var appVersionShort: String { getInfo("CFBundleShortVersion") }
    
    fileprivate func getInfo(_ str: String) -> String { infoDictionary?[str] as? String ?? "⚠️" }
}
```

And assign to menu line:

```
struct MyApp: App {
    @NSApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
        // Replacement of standard About window
        .commands {
            CommandGroup(replacing: CommandGroupPlacement.appInfo) {
                Button("About \(Bundle.main.appName)") { appDelegate.showAboutWnd() }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Bonus: Support of "\n" in Copyright

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the good, detailed answer!